# OpenERP: Pass context from server (back-end) to form (front-end)

Tags: forms, treeview, odoo, onchange

Question about dynamic views in OpenERP.

Inside a `form` view I have a `tree` view of a one2many field. In this `tree` view I'd like to hide/show the **entire column** (not just individual cells) depending on the contents of the parent `form` view. E.g. a column should be hidden if in the [parent's] form view a certain field is filled or a checkbox is ticked.

AFAIK, the only way to hide the entire column is to use context:

```
<field name='my_column' invisible="not context.get('showMyColumn',False)">
```

My question is: **How to pass context from server (back-end) to form (front-end)?**

I know how to do the opposite (pass context from form to server). And I know how to pass context from button's action function to form:

```
return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window', ..., 'context': ctx_updated}
```

But I'd like to know how to update form's context from the `write()` method of the form view's object or from it's `on_change` method of the object's field my column listens to.

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: I don't think you need to do it trough the `context`. How do you determine if the column have to be visible?

Comment: Updated the post:
E.g. a column should be hidden if in the [parent's] form view a certain field is filled or a checkbox is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean ony this example
"Updated the post: E.g. a column should be hidden if in the [parent's] form view a certain field is filled or a checkbox is ticked."

then I think the best way is to:

```
<field name="value_ids" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('parent.text_field','not in',['']),('parent.mandatory','=', True)]}">
```

So field is invisible if text in parent's field is set, or checkbox is checked.

If you wish to make it more complicated, you can create additional functional field in your parent's object

```
def _visible(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    result = {}
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[obj.id] = True
    return result

_columns = {
    'visible': : fields.function(_visible, type='boolean',string='Visible'),
```

there you define when it should be visible, and when not.

In your parent's view you add that field

And after you can just call

```
<field name="value_ids" attrs="{'parent.invisible':[('parent.visible','=',True)]}">
```

I would do it in that way.

Comment: Good and helpful answer for the general case but it doesn't work (at least for me) when you try to hide an entire column in one2many widget. It seems that only the `visible='False'` doest the job but there you cannot use values from other fields....

Comment: Andrei, exactly. What you CAN use inside the 'invisible' tag is a context. So the problem boils down to passing data to the context from the server - exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: Tadeusz, thanks for pointing out how to hide individual cells on a cell-by-cell basis. However, in my question I explicitly stated that I need to hide the entire column, not just blank out individual cells. I didn't try your solution, but I'm 146% sure it will blank out all the cells in a row, as this approach can be met in pretty much every OERP addon out there.

Only the 'invisible' tag on a field can hide the entire column, but unfortunately it only accepts static objects (compiled only once, at module loading). Context is one such object, and it does work from the button action function.